# Override method of Type class (e.g String, Number ... ) in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, overriding, overloading

Overload operator on the Type class sound strange in practice but just on learning purpose, is that possible?

`String` or `Number`in Kotlin have build-in methods / operators as `plus` or `+` ... Is there any way to modify these build-in-s, because `extension function` can not override the build-in one.

In Kotlinglang doc, Kotlin didn't have `primitive type`, all is `Object` means that it can be modified?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, so you need to replace an existing method of a class, then no, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload means something completely different than override. You *can* overload these functions with extension functions by using different input parameter types. You *cannot* override (replace) them with different functionality.

Although these platform types are classes (there is no concept of a primitive), they are `final` classes, meaning you cannot subclass them and therefore cannot override their functions.